# Odoo - Bulk Update Product Variant Internal ID

Tags: odoo, export-to-csv, odoo-11

I am working with odoo community edition 11 and have been looking for the correct way to bulk import internal reference numbers for product variants.

[image: product export]

I have attempted to export the data in a usable format however each time I am able to get the necessary fields, the product variants are duplicated in the export. In the image below you can see that each product in this case is shown twice.

[image: export data]

With approximately 1800 variant products currently, this issue isn't something that's a simple workaround. And this number is expected to increase dramatically over the next few weeks.

I'm looking for guidance on how to get the initial export of all product variants with no assigned internal reference to function properly.

The fields I need to be able to bring down is the product ID  (reference for import) the internal reference  (or blank) and the variant attributes assigned to that particular product variant.

Any assistance in pushing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

** Output from first answer below:

[image: export image]

[image]

Comment: How do you mean the product variant is duplicated? Can you show some examples? There should be only the records you have selected. For variant attributes, will product variant name with variant attributes in `(parenthesis)` work?

Comment: Added an image of the data export which shows an example of the export duplication.

Comment: this is not exported from product variants list, is it?

Comment: Master Data on the inventory module, product variants, selected products from the variants list, and exported. Export selection image added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Inventory > Master data > Product variants, select a product and got to action>export, select radio button `Export all Data`. Select columns 'Display name, Internal Reference, ID', then choose `save export` and save the export with any name. Now cancel the export, select all product variants, go to export again and this time keep 'Import compatible' selected, choose that saved export from earlier.

You will have exported list of product variants with column `Full name` which contains 'variant attributes' in it. and you can import this modifying the `Internal reference` column.

For example, check this from a new demo database in odoo:
[image: Product variant export]

Comment: This outputs [id] [display name] [.id] [default code] while there is no duplication the attribute values aren't anywhere to be seen.

Comment: variant attribute values are right in the display name column after product name, what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you also need the `variant name` for example `BWS-Orintation`? Just value won't serve your purpose?

Comment: Variant name would be helpful but I can certainly create a lookup script to compare value if necessary in the event that the actual attribute value isn\t able to be accessed properly. ++ output from export added to question.

Comment: if it outputs just HORZ or BW for example, that is more than sufficient. The actual name of the variant isn't important because their values are the specific identifier and are all unique.

Comment: Yes exactly, i thought so. But `Display name` field of product variant is always included 'create variant' attribute value by default, I even checked this with a new demo database, I am not sure why it is exporting only product template name in your case!

Comment: Could this be due to the fact that the items are uploaded through CSV, maybe the import is forcing a value which would otherwise be generated by the system automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188128/discussion-between-arryph-and-runeworks-gaming).